# Calling multi argument Javascript function in XSLT

Tags: 2010, javascript, xslt, data-view-web-part

I am working on a data view web part. I am using Java script for some of my functioning and having trouble with calling javascript function with more than one arguments while single argument function is working fine.

When i used this single argument function, it worked fine:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function PrintElement(loopPosition)
    {
        alert("1");
    }
    PrintElement(<xsl:value-of select="$pos"/>);                    
</script>
```

Later on, i tried to add one more argument but it is not calling the javascript function and page is giving error on  the line where function is being called.

I tried the following but no luck:

```
PrintElement(<xsl:value-of select="$pos"/>,<xsl:value-of select="$FPageName"/>);
PrintElement(<xsl:value-of select="$pos"/>+","+<xsl:value-of select="$FPageName"/>);
PrintElement("'"+<xsl:value-of select="$pos"/>+"'","'"+<xsl:value-of select="$FPageName"+"'"/>);
PrintElement("'"+<xsl:value-of select="$pos"/>+"','"+<xsl:value-of select="$FPageName"+"'"/>);
```

First and Second statementdoes not call the function and third throws an error.

Could someone please help me with the exact sysntax and elaborate a bit.

Comment: PrintElement("'"+<xsl:value-of select="$pos"/>+"','"+<xsl:value-of select="$FPageName" />"'"); should work

Comment: It should but it doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I made it work. It goes like this:

```
PrintElement('<xsl:value-of select="$pos"/>','<xsl:value-of select="$FPageName"/>');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass two arguments to a Javascript function, then that function needs to be defined to have two arguments. If it is defined to take only one argument, then, of course it will error.

So, change your Javascript function to accept and process a second argument along the lines of this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function PrintElement(loopPosition, PageName)
    {
        alert(loopPosition);
        alert(PageName);   
    }
</script>
```

Comment: My mistake, I didnt explained properly. Its already there.